# Play M4B file in MediaElement class in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

Is it possible to play M4B audiobook files in WPF media element class? If not, can someone please help me find an alternate solution? Trying to create a WPF apps that can play M4B files.

Answer (score 0):

Finally used NAudio library to play the files:

```
private WaveOutEvent outputDevice;
private AudioFileReader audioFile;

private void OnButtonPlayClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (outputDevice == null)
    {
        outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
        outputDevice.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
    }
    if (audioFile == null)
    {
        audioFile = new AudioFileReader(@"D:\example.m4b");
        outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
    }
    outputDevice.Play();
}
```

I created a WPF application to play M4B audiobooks [here](https://github.com/mnakka9/Audibly-WPF-M4B-AudiobookPlayer).